# Forced https redirects causing infinite loop

Tags: iis, amazon-web-services, https

I have created a Load balancing  environment on AWS with help of elastic beanstalk. I want to redirect all http traffic to https. The certificate i am using is the one which get for free in AWS certificate manager. I have used the accepted answer in this post

[IIS 7 Require SSL automatically redirect to https://](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28057/iis-7-require-ssl-automatically-redirect-to-https), but this is causing infinite redirects. How can i perform redirects on the load balancer level? I have a windows server. There are many answers for apache or Nginx but none for windows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791820/redirect-to-https-through-url-rewrite-in-iis-within-elastic-beanstalks-load-bal

Comment: @FedericoSierra this is also causing infinite redirect's even on the localhost

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you listen 443 port from ELB and land to 80 port on your IIS (windows server).  I know this is not right answer but it will work as of now till you resolve or found something to resolve.

Comment: thats exactly what is happening. I want to redirect http traffic to https. Your answer won't help with that in any way. FYI i have already got the answer from the link in comments